# How do I write a JOIN query in SQL linking to other tables? (Specific q in description)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> The output for this query should show parent/carer title, first name and surname in a single column, and the total number of activities taken by all children registered to that parent/carer.

This is what I have so far:

```
    SELECT CONCAT(carer_title, ' ', carer_fname, ' ', carer_sname) AS 'carer name'
    FROM Carer;
```

Giving me the first column:

[image]

I appreciate this is tricky without looking at the full schema but here's the relevant info, let me know if you think I'm missing any information.

Schema: [image: Schema]

Relevant tables and columns:

**Carer** | carer_id |carer_title | carer_fname | carer_sname | carer_phone | carer_address1 | carer_address2 | carer_town | carer_pcode

**Child** | child_id | child_fname | child_sname | child_gender | child_dob | child_carer | child_school

**Childactivity** (Table linking children and activities they partake in made up of foreign keys) | child_id | activity_id

**Activity** | activity_id | activity_name | activity_day | activity_fee

How would you go about adding a column which finds the total number of activities taken by all children registered to each carer?

Comment: `child carer` is a column name with a space? Is it the foreign key corresponding to `Carer.carer_id`?

Comment: *"total number of activities taken by all children"*: does that mean only activities should be counted in which *all* children participate? Or should any activities be counted in which at least *one* child participates?

Comment: *child_carer, yes exactly. And in which at least one child participates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the other involved tables, and count per group:

```
select    concat(carer_title, ' ', carer_fname, ' ', carer_sname) as `carer name`,
          count(*) `number of activities`
from      carer
left join child on child.child_carer = carer.carer_id
left join childactivity on childactivity.child_id = child.child_id
group by  carer.id;
```

If only distinct activities should be counted, so not counting twice when two children participate in the same activity, then replace `count(*)` by `count(distinct childactivity.activity_id)`